# Django - ForeignKey : Is it possible get multiple kind of objects referencing itself?

Tags: django, django-models

**models.py**

```
class BaseModel(TimeStampedModel):
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
        ordering = ('-created',)

    def deactivate(self):
        # Make all child objects is_active=False


class ModelA(BaseModel)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class ModelB(BaseModel):
    model_a = models.ForeignKey(ModelA)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class ModelC(BaseModel):
    model_a = models.ForeignKey(ModelA)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

As you can see above, I want to make `deactivate` method for setting all childeren's `is_active` field as `False`.

Someone might think of this way:

```
def deactivate(self):
    # Make all child objects is_active=False
    b = ModelB.objects.filter(parent=self)
    c = ModelC.objects.filter(parent=self)

    for obj in b:
        obj.is_active = False
        obj.save()

    for obj in c:
        obj.is_active = False
        obj.save()
```

But it only works for `ModelA` which `ModelB`, `ModelC` are referencing, not available for all `models`.(e.g I I called `modelB.delete()`, it won't deactivate its child model(if `ModelB` had child model)

I want to make it `general` method so that I can use it in any `models`:

```
all_model_objects = ModelsReferencingMe.objects.filter(parent=self)
```

Is there any way to implement this?

Comment: use something called abstract model

Comment: How could that helps?

Comment: the issue u r facing now has something to do inheritance. u want to make methods/attr in grandparent visible to the grandchild or great grandchild, abstract model is just something that i recommend u to have a look which may solve ur problem

Comment: @Mox I think you don't understand what I want..

Answer (score 0):

I think you can make use of [Model._meta](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/meta/) API here.

```
class BaseModel(object):
    deactivation_field = None  # don't forget to override in subclasses

    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
        ordering = ('-created',)

    def deactivate(self):
        related_models = [
            f.related_model for f in self.__class__._meta.get_fields()
            if (f.one_to_many or f.one_to_one)
            and f.auto_created and not f.concrete
        ]
        filter_clause = {self.deactivation_field: self}
        for model in related_models:
            items = model.objects.filter(**filter_clause)
            items.update(is_active=False)
            for item in items:
                item.deactivate()
```

And use it as follows:

```
class ModelA(BaseModel)
     deactivation_field = 'model_a'

     name = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class ModelB(BaseModel):
     deactivation_field = 'model_b'

     model_a = models.ForeignKey(ModelA)
     name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

Explanation: each time you call `.deactivate()` on some model instance, it will loop through models, set `is_active` to `False` in a single SQL `UPDATE` (a single update for each table, of course) and then loop through all given instances, calling `.deactivate()` for each instance. The purpose of `deactivation_field` I added is to let the `deactivate` method know how to filter items of child models. For instance, in case of `ModelA` `filter_clause` will yield `.filter(model_a=self)`, in case of `ModelB` - `.filter(model_b=self)`, and so on.

There are, of course, some caveats:

1. `QuerySet.update` does not call `.save` or any signals, so if that's an issue to you, replace a single update query with individual `.save` calls.
2. The code above does not expect any other related models except for `BaseModel` subclasses. If there are other models, make sure to check for that yourself.
3. Maintaining `deactivation_field` is up to you, if you forget about it in subclasses - do expect errors.
4. Do note that this idea of yours requires a deep recursion with nested loops and is a performance nightmare.

Comment: Your answer is helpful but cannot solve perfectly. Could you check my code and errors, please? https://gist.github.com/rightx2/794eb93978846071fd2817fd4689d3bf

Comment: @user3595632 Not sure what are you trying to achieve there. Why recursion? Please add comments or give some explanation, otherwise I'm not sure how can I help.

Comment: Please refer to this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40701714/django-implement-cascade-field-change